# OnActivityResult for 2 different activites

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

I am trying to initialize/ turn on the NFC and the BT modules in same activity.
I need them both to be enabled before I continue the task.

I do understand that OnResultActivity is Async so I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to achieve it?

Here's most of the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initBT();
        initNFC();

        Intent nextIntent;      
        if(SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(MainActivity.this).length() == 0)
        {
            nextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        }
        else
        {
            nextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
        }   
        startActivity(nextIntent);
        finish();
    }


    private void initBT() {
        if(BTModule.GetInstance().initBT().equals(Constants.eBluetoothStatus.BT_DISABLED)){
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BTModule.GetAdapter().ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }

    private void initNFC(){

        mNFCState = NFCModule.initNFC(this);
        if(mNFCState == eNFCStatus.NFC_NOT_SUPPORTED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not suppoeted for this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(mNFCState == eNFCStatus.NFC_DISABLED){
            Intent nfcIntent;
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16){
                nfcIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);  
            }
            else{
            nfcIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
            }
            startActivity(nfcIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable NFC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is up and running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == eBluetoothStatus.BT_OK.ordinal()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "BT is up and running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

As I am a newbie please feel free to correct me if I am wrong with anything :)

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use **startActivityForResult** instead of **startActivity** in **initNFC** method. Also define 2 boolean variables like **isNfcEnabled** and **isBtEnabled**. In **onActivityResult** method check those booleans. If both of them are enable, do whatever you want.